# BoxCast Parameter Values Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting

Basically there is no proper example and no debug draw method exist for BoxCast for Unity Physics 2D. So it become really difficult to judge for actual implementation.

I am referring [Physics2D.BoxCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html) for writing actual code so actual syntax you can follow from this link.

Here is the code, I have written:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(
new Vector2(slicer[i].position.x, slicer[i].position.y), 
Vector2.one * 0.01f, 0f, slicer[i].right, 10f, boxMask);
```

But this code is not working for me in actual game.
Here is my representation for exact requirements.

[image]

From cutter two BoxCast rays will passed and I want to detect object and position at which these rays get collide.

So for doing this what modification, I require to do in BoxCast method?

Comment: Ensure that your objects are in your layermask filter used (boxMask) or change this layer to the desired

Comment: Yes that already exist in proper layermask because Physics2D.Raycast method working properly but Physics2D.Raycast can't able to satisfy my requirements so I am approaching for BoxCast.